# Resizing mac partition on a volume with boot-camp

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, windows, partition

On my mac I have two partitions, and I want to create a new one. One partition has Mountain Lion and the other has Windows 7 (through Boot-Camp). I want to create a new mac partition, and for that I want to remove about 10Gb of space from the mac partition I already have and use that space for the new one.

I have searched quite a bit and I found so many different answers I can't really make up a plan on my mind, so I decided to post a question here explaining my situation in hopes of getting an answer tailored to my needs.

I know that resizing windows partitions can lead to big problems, but the thing is I don't want to resize the windows partition, just the mac partition. Does that still cause problems? If so, what would you advise (preferably something you have already tried)?

Lastly, I found out about [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php), which is recommended on various places, but I'm at a loss on how to use it (for example, how can I put it on my USB pen?).

Comment: VTC as dupe only to link to newer answer, as iPartition is no longer the recommended app for this task.

Answer (score 2):

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend [**iPartition**](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php).

> With its intuitive yet powerful user interface, iPartition makes it easy to create, destroy, resize or format partitions on your hard disks, whether internal, external, fixed or removable.

iPartition even allows you to **modify Boot Camp partitions** without any problems. iPartition will reconfigure the Windows partitions automatically.

> You can use iPartition on drives that contain Boot Camp volumes; in fact, you can even resize your Windows partitions, and let iPartition take care of reconfiguring the Windows boot process for you.
>
> [image: iPartition Screenshot 1]
>
> [image: iPartition Screenshot 2]